# Update a multi-valued column through checkbox values

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have recently started using Access with VBA.

Problem Statement : There are 4 optional subjects say Maths,Economics,Computer Science,Home Science. A column called 'Subject' for each student stores the optional subjects(the number of subjects varies with each student).

What I did : I made a multi-valued field in the table called 'Subject' using the lookup wizard in design view. In the form view, I have these 4 checkboxes listed to select and submit . When I try writing an update statement for field 'Subject' using the checkbox values it gives me an error.

Is there some other way to solve this problem or can I correct the method I have used?

Thanks !

Comment: I would recommend to do not use tables with multi-valued columns, they cause more problems than benefits

Comment: I agree, create table where you will store optional subjects - you can easy insert new value once subject is selected, or remove from table for each student.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table with 2 fields; Student ID and Subject.  Write all subjects into that table.  When you need to return them, either use a subform (linked on StudentID) or create a pivot table if necessary.

Multi-Value columns are not optimal, they create a lot of problems.  If you absolutely **must** use one, then you need to parse the data when you extract it.  When you first write it, you need to write a statement like;

```
MyStr = "" 
If Me.Checkbox1 = True then
  MyStr = MyStr & "SomeValue, "
EndIf
If Me.Checkbox2 = True then
  MyStr = MyStr & "SomeValue2, "
EndIf
If Me.Checkbox3 = True then
  MyStr = MyStr & "SomeValue3, "
EndIf
If Me.Checkbox4 = True then
  MyStr = "SomeValue4, "
EndIf  

If Len(MyStr) > 2 Then
  MyStr = Left(MyStr, Len(MyStr) - 2)
EndIF
```

What this does is continually append the values you assign to the checkboxes, and then removes the last 2 characters (which should be ", ") so you have a complete string.  Then you write MyStr to your Subject field.

When you go to read this info, you'll need to parse it out into an array and work backwards, determining which checkbox should be marked based on the values in your array.